# Rationalising the Surds

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, partial-fractions, radicals

Please help me rationalise and simplify:  $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2} - 1}  \ - \  \frac{2}{\sqrt{3} - 2} \ .  $$

I have tried using the cube of the denominator and the square of the denominator on the second one but it stuffs up when I try to simplify.

Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if I have interpreted your expression correctly.

Comment: Why on earth did you said *minus* , knowing *-* exists?

Comment: RecklessReckoner-Yes, you have. Except i have no idea what all those symbols mean(newbie alert)  :)

Comment: to my dear (cough cough)chubakueno, i have no idea.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** $(2^{1/3}-1)(1+2^{1/3}+2^{2/3})=(2-1)$

$(\sqrt3 - 2)(\sqrt3 +2)=(3-2^2) $

Comment: I know this is exactly what it tells you not to do, but thanks Awesome. nice picture.:)

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

The hints provided by Awesome are sufficient to get the answer immediately.
In general if $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial  $f(x)$ with rational coefficients (in your case $x^3-2=0$), and you are asked to find the value
of something like $ \frac{1}{\alpha^2+a\alpha +b}$, or  inverse of a general polynomial expression $g(\alpha)$, carry out Euclidean algorithm for gcd with $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (same procedure in Bezout's theorem with integers)  which will give an identity $a(x)f(x) +b(x) g(x)\equiv 1$.

Substituting $\alpha$ in the identity first term evaluates to zero and we get that $b(\alpha)$   is the inverse of $g(\alpha)$ we are looking for. Here $b(\alpha)$ being a polynomial expression there are are no denominators.

Comment: Thanks must go to you too-P Vanchinathan...